# Background images flanking the Bootstrap container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, background-image

I want 2 background images, that both hug the Container div on both left and right side, keep in mind im using Bootstrap  Framework.

I want the images to follow the content, just like https://www.komplett.dk/k/kcf.aspx?tag=weekly1 (They have the Yellow boxes on each side) I want that on my bootstrap template.

```
<body>

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x50&text=Logo" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Heading Row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/900x350" alt="">
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-md-8 -->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h1 style="color:green;">Fleksible</h1>
                <p>Navns vision er at være den billigste, mest fleksible og professionelle løsning indenfor IT reperation. Med en timepris på 120,- + fleres års erfarring inden for installation, reperation mm. Mener vi at vores vision pligtopfyldes.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#">Call to Action!</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
        <hr>
        <!-- Call to Action Well -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="well text-center">
                    Kontakt os for bestilling, eller en samtale angående dit problem på 26 39 05 00
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
        <!-- Content Row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h2>Heading 1</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe rem nisi accusamus error velit animi non ipsa placeat. Recusandae, suscipit, soluta quibusdam accusamus a veniam quaerat eveniet eligendi dolor consectetur.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">More Info</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h2>Heading 2</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe rem nisi accusamus error velit animi non ipsa placeat. Recusandae, suscipit, soluta quibusdam accusamus a veniam quaerat eveniet eligendi dolor consectetur.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">More Info</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h2>Heading 3</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe rem nisi accusamus error velit animi non ipsa placeat. Recusandae, suscipit, soluta quibusdam accusamus a veniam quaerat eveniet eligendi dolor consectetur.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">More Info</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2014</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.container -->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

That is my entire body, I hope someone have experience with Bootstrap Framework 3, that might have been trying the same, and found a solution to the problem.

Comment: Yea sorry about that didnt wanna sound like a spoiled kid, i have tried some difference solution that didnt work out.

I have tried to make a image that was full size : 1170 px : within that image there was a white image, that was same width as the content. That didnt work when u got to lower resolution. 

I have tried to center the background image aswell, and that didnt do the job either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can solve this with just bootstrap but i'd do something like this. If you don't need to support below ie8, I would use :before and :after elements on the container to hold the background images, then position them absolutely like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/ggomhr0y/

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.container:before, .container:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    top: 100px; // Whatever
    width: 100px; // Whatever
    height: 100px; // Whatever
}

.container:before {
    left: -100px;
    background-image: url("Your image left");
}

.container:after {
    right: -100px;
    background-image: url("Your image right");
}
```

This assumes you know the width and height of the background image and you can set the container to relative. If browser support is an issue, you can just use divs instead to achieve the same.

Comment: That solved it, thanks alot the help was really apreciated. Atleast for now it seems like sealing the deal ;) . Really really thanks for the help :)

Comment: Nice. Here it is with Bootstrap in effect. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/ggomhr0y/1/